# Office Add-in (agave) error - not rendering task pane content

Tags: c#, .net, office-addins

I am trying to follow the [tutorial](http://dev.office.com/getting-started/addins) on dev.office.com for writing an Office Add-in.

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with office tools installed.

Steps:

- File > New Project
- In new project dialog: Templates > Visual C# > Office/Sharepoint > Apps > App for Office
- Fill in Name/location, click OK
- Choose Task pane in Wizard and any permutation of Word/Excel/PPT options (all have same result)
- Wait for template to load
- Hit F5 or click Start

Result is Excel (or Word) opens with a Pane on the right side, but with an error:

> ADD-IN ERROR Sorry, you seem to have lost your network and/or Internet
>   connection. Click "Retry" once you're back online.

I am running Office 2016. I have no network issues.

I have tried reinstalling office tools and rebooting. No success. I have not found this error elsewhere on the web yet.

This is a recently rebuilt dev machine - within a week or so. I had it working once over a month ago, but it inexplicably fails now in my fresh environment.

I would appreciate any help getting this to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the punchline is that this is actually the current state of office add-ins - broken for everyone from what I can tell.

The workaround is simply to remove the calculated web app location in the app manifest and replace it with your web app's url:

```
<DefaultSettings>
  <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44300/" />
</DefaultSettings>
```