# Dialog is not displaying in the word add-in

Tags: dialog, office365, word-addins

I am trying to show a dialog in the word add-in I am working on right now. This is how I implement it within my code

```
function loadServers() {

    var dialogUrl = 'https://' + location.host + '/App/Signin/signin.html';

    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(dialogUrl, { width: 50, height: 50, requireHTTPS: true }, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {

        }
    });
}
```

But when I execute above code snippet It show me below Add-in error

> ADD-IN ERROR Sorry, you seem to have lost your network and/or Internet connection. Click "Retry" once you're back online.

I already tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444192/office-add-in-agave-error-not-rendering-task-pane-content). But it didn't work for me. When I tried HTTP instead of the HTTPS, nothing happens. But when I try HTTPS, I got this error. Does anyone has an idea, how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you verified that the URL that you are generating is valid (E.g. the cert is valid)?  From your code it looks like the url is valid but worth double checking cert.  Other things you can try are ensuring that the domain is in the <AppDomain> list on the manifest. Also the 'requireHTTPS' is no longer a required parameter (it always requires https).  Latest [docs] (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync)

Comment: @Humberto Lezama Thanks for the reply. I fixed the problem. SSL enable URL should add into <AppDomain> list on the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by adding the URL into the AppDomains entry in the Add-in manifest.